# Running Less.js for windows with Clean-Css enabled get "object has no method 'install' error

Tags: node.js, less, clean-css

I am using the following git:[less.js-windows](https://github.com/duncansmart/less.js-windows). I've installed clean-css with the following command:

```
npm install -g less-plugin-clean-css
```

now I am trying to run lessc with this:

```
lessc -clean-css main.less main.css
```

and I get the following error:

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'install'
> at PluginManager.addPlugin (C:\Users\oscar.polo\Downloads\less.js-windows-v2.1.1\bin\node_modules\less\lib\less\plugin-manager.js:28:12)
> at PluginManager.addPlugins (C:\Users\oscar.polo\Downloads\less.js-windows-v2.1.1\bin\node_modules\less\lib\less\plugin-manager.js:18:18)
> at Object.render (C:\Users\oscar.polo\Downloads\less.js-windows-v2.1.1\bin\node_modules\less\lib\less\render.js:31:27)
> at C:\Users\oscar.polo\Downloads\less.js-windows-v2.1.1\bin\node_modules\less\lib\less\render.js:18:24
> at doResolve (C:\Users\oscar.polo\Downloads\less.js-windows-v2.1.1\bin\node_modules\promise\lib\core.js:91:5)
> at new Promise (C:\Users\oscar.polo\Downloads\less.js-windows-v2.1.1\bin\node_modules\promise\lib\core.js:71:3)
> at Object.render (C:\Users\oscar.polo\Downloads\less.js-windows-v2.1.1\bin\node_modules\less\lib\less\render.js:17:20)
> at parseLessFile (C:\Users\oscar.polo\Downloads\less.js-windows-v2.1.1\bin\node_modules\less\bin\lessc:381:10)
> at evalmachine.:266:14
> at C:\Users\oscar.polo\Downloads\less.js-windows-v2.1.1\bin\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:102:5

Any ideas whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Parameter **--clean-css** means that *.css file will be compressed using **clean-css tool**. Maybe you have no it installed?
Try this to install it:

```
npm install -g less-plugin-clean-css
```

This may help you: [Clean CSS](http://lesscss.org/usage/#v2-upgrade-guide-clean-css)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure will it help, but try to do this:

```
lessc --clean-css main.less main.css
```

Because based on [documentation](https://github.com/duncansmart/less.js-windows#usage) usage it should be run with double dash before parameter "clean-css"